# Login to flask web server via android buildozer app

Tags: python, android, flask, kivy, buildozer

I have a python flask web server and a python buildozer app with kivy running on android.
Now i want to login to my web server via app and upload files (e.g. pictures, texts).

I'm new to this and would like to know how it is possible?

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

just use something like ehm i dont know the name ah sockets

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).